# How to find the minimum number of moves?

Tags: chessboard.js

Note:- I've solved the above problem with back-tracking approach,by trying out all different ways, I am in search of a very efficient way/pattern.

We are given a chessboard of size 'N' X 'N' . But it can contain any numbers of white-squares and black-squares , that too in any-order .

Say there are 'a'-squares of white color and 'b'-squares of black-color , then ,

[ a+b=n*n ]

We have to keep on making move with black-squares on the chessboard till there is no move left.

This is what happens in a move:-

1)We choose a black-square at co-ordinate:-(row,column) and move it to (row-1,column+1) , only if the co-ordinate (row-1,column+1) also contains a black-square . After it is moved to the new-position , the old-position,i.e, [row,column] becomes empty, i.e , its color turns to white .

OR

2)We choose a black-square at co-ordinate:-(row,column) and move it to (row-1,column-1) , only if the co-ordinate (row-1,column-1) also contains a black-square .After it is moved to the new-position , the old-position,i.e, [row,column] becomes empty, i.e , its color turns to white .

We have to end this game in least number of moves and the question is to find the sequence of those moves .

Lets denote black-square by '1' and white-square by '0' .. ...

Example:-

3X3 chessboard:-

0 1 0

1 0 1

0 0 0

Sequence of move(s) which ends the game in minimum number of moves : -

1)Move the black-square at [1,0] to [0,1]...Now the chessboard looks like this : -

0 1 0

0 0 1

0 0 0

2) We move the black-square at [1,2] to [0,1] and the chessboard looks like this:-

0 1 0

0 0 0

0 0 0

Now, there are no valid moves left and the game ends :-)

Given a chessboard of size 'N' x 'N' and any configuration of black and white-squares, how to find the sequence of moves which ends the game in minimum number of moves ?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I don't want the code, I just want to know the idea behind the solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can view this problem would be as a graph traversal. Since we are looking for the *shortest* move, we can exploit our knowledge of graph traversal algorithms and consider using a breadth-first traversal.

We are going to need to be able to do a couple of things to achieve this:

- Given a chessboard in some configuration, **compute all the legal moves that can be taken**.
- Given a chessboard in some configuration, and a legal move, **compute the configuration of the chessboard after that move is applied**.
- Given a chessboard in some configuration, **check if this configuration is *terminal*** (such  that no other moves can be made from this position, and the game is over).

Now that we have this, let's see how we can map this problem to a graph traversal problem.

- Let the initial configuration be the *root* node of your graph.
- The *edges* leading out of the root node are the legal moves we can make from this position.
- The *children nodes* that these edges point towards are the configuration that result from applying the move on the edge label to the parent node.

Then the process of finding the shortest path to a terminal positions would look like this (starting at the root node):

- Expand the children of the root node, by generating all legal moves given this configuration.
- Check each of the children to see if a terminal configuration has been reached.
- If not, expand the children in a breath-first fashion (this [link](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/breadth-first/) from BU has more details about the implementation detail of such a traversal)

The magic of the breath-first traversal kicks in here. From here we repeat this process of expanding a node, checking for terminal configurations, and going down a level in the graph if we don't find such a configuration.

**Once we do find a terminal configuration, we know that the path (edges representing moves made) from our root node (initial configuration) to our terminal node (game over position), is the shortest**. All we do now is count the number of edges back to the root node, and we know what the minimum number of moves is.

Comment: Note:- I've solved the above problem with back-tracking/graph approach,by trying out all different ways, I am in search of a very efficient way/pattern which solves the problem in O(n^2) time, where 'n' is the size of chessboard